# Directing a negative statement to someone that is actually intended for the speaker itself

Tags: speech

In spoken English, sometimes people address the audience but in fact, they mean themselves. An example:

> You haven't been attacked and fearful for your life and remained
>   optimistic the entire time.

What they actually mean is the following:

> I was attacked and I was fearful of my life and I remained optimistic
>   the entire time. You do not understand this because you haven't
>   experience it.

Is this a known English grammar? Or is this something that have been discussed in Language or Linguistics studies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English distinguishes three persons -- in their usual roles, the first (the person speaking), the second (the person spoken to), and the third (the person spoken about).  That is, **I**<sup>(**1st**)</sup> tell **you**<sup>(**2nd**)</sup> about **him**<sup>(**3rd**)</sup>.

There are two situations in which the sentences are grammatically second person but not semantically. I.e., the pronouns in the sentences are *you*, but the narrator is not addressing someone else.  The first is called *second person narrative*, in which the narrator of a story relates what is his own story but in the second person.  (I.e., the second person is a substitute for the first person.)  A commonly-cited example is Jay McInerney's *Bright Lights, Big City*:

> You are not the kind of guy who would be at a place like this at this
>   time of the morning. But here you are, and you cannot say that the
>   terrain is entirely unfamiliar, although the details are fuzzy.

Here's another example from Amanda Jenkins' *Damage*:

> When you open your eyes, the joyless feeling has already crawled onto
>   your chest.  The ceiling of your room presses you down into the
>   mattress.  The air settles in your lungs so heavy that it’s almost too
>   much trouble to breathe.

This usage is to be distinguished from literature written from the point of view of an omniscient narrator who addresses the protagonist.  That's the ordinary use of the second person, the narrator speaking to someone else.  In second person narrative, the narrator relates his own story.  We understand that McInerney's protagonist means "I'm not that kind of guy" and Jenkins' means "The ceiling is pressing me down into the mattress."

The second such usage is called *second person indeterminate*, in which the grammatical second person is a substitute for the (unnamed) third person. In your example, the narrator (the first person) says

> You do not understand this because you haven't experienced it.

but what the narrator means is

> Those who haven't experienced it, do not understand.